# expressionengine removing title requirement

Tags: expressionengine

How can I remove the requirement of having to need a title for my entry?
I basically wanted to use expression engine to list snippets of text as entries but they really have no title they are snippets. Is there a way to have a title automatically generate maybe a number everytime.
What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an add-on for that: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sp-title-filler/